# Looking for product reviews dataset

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, dataset, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on a school project on product analysis which is based on sentimental analysis. I've been looking for a training dataset for quite a some time now and what I've been able to find so far is a dataset for movie reviews. My question is, can I use this dataset for training the classifier, i.e. will it have an effect on the accuracy of classification? If so, does anyone here know where I can get a free dataset for product reviews?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using some textual model like the bag of words model.

From my experiments, **you usually don't get good results when changing from one domain to another** (even if the train data set and the test are all products, but of different categories!). 

Think of it logically, an oven that gets hot quickly usually indicate a good product. Is it also the same for laptops?

When I experimented with it a few years ago I used **amazon comments** as both train set and also to test my algorithms.

The comments are short and informative and were enough to get ~80% accuracy. The 'ground' truth was the stars system, where 1-2 stars were 'negative', 3 stars - 'neutral', and 4-5 stars 'positive'.

I used a pearl [script from esuli.it](http://www.esuli.it/fossil/repo/amazonReviewsDownloader/index) to crawl amazon's comments.